# Pseudo-Random number generator bases on FPIS 186-2

Tags: java

I'm looking for java implementation of a pseudo random number generator based on FIPS 186-2. I  couldn't find any implementation of this for JDK7.

Does anybody know a implementation of PRNG for FIPS 186-2?

Comment: The algorithm is up on the internet for everyone to see. Why not give implementing it yourself a go, and come to us if/when you get stuck?

Comment: Just because FIPS 186-2 is most likely used in a crypto-context and the first thing any good cryptographic course teaches you is "Don't try to implement any primitive yourself."

Comment: The [IAIK-JCE](http://jce.iaik.tugraz.at/sic/Products/Core-Crypto-Toolkits/JCA_JCE/features/Random-Number-Generators) seems to have various implementations but I believe it's a commercial product (free for educational and research purposes).

Comment: @christopher, assuming OP is looking for this PRNG for production code, writing your own implementation if you're not already an expert at cryptography is borderline criminal.  NEVER roll your own crypto for anything other than a learning exercise.  [Source](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cryptographic_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Rule_-_Only_use_widely_accepted_implementations_of_cryptographic_algorithms)